# Mis-alignment of badge count on user cards (CSS "bug")

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

This is a pretty minor CSS "bug" but thought I'd mention it. Apologies for splitting hairs here, but the rest of the site's formatting and styling is so crystal-clear this little detail ends up being a bit distracting.

The number for badge count on a user's card in many cases can butt up against the badge icon. This happens on user cards in the ["Questions"](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions) view as well as on individual questions and answers. This is visible in Chrome (Windows and Mac), Firefox, and Safari. Please see examples below.

*On the questions listing:*

[image]

*On individual questions and answers:*

[image]

**Solution:** tweaking the margin on`.user-details .badgecount` and on `.badgecount` would make a worthwhile improvement. For example:

[image]

Please consider this request for a CSS tweak for the site.

Thanks!

Comment: This should be easy to do. I'll let the StackExchange folks reply to this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has been revised by the Stack Exchange team. The badge counts no longer bump into the badge icons. Thanks for the really quick response!

If an official answer is posted here I'll accept that instead, but posting this for now.